# Relocation Truncated to Fit error in NASM x86_64

Tags: linker, nasm, relocation, truncated

I'm using a computer with an Intel Core 2 CPU and 2GB of RAM. My OS is Ubuntu 9.04.
When I try to compile this code:

```
;programma per la simulazione di un terminale su PC, ottenuto utilizzando l'8250

;in condizione di loopback , cioè Tx=Rx


section .code64

section .data


TXDATA  EQU 03F8H ;TRASMETTITORE

RXDATA  EQU 03F8H ;RICEVITORE

BAUDLSB  EQU 03F8H ;DIVISORE DI BAUD RATE IN LSB

BAUDMSB  EQU 03F9H ;DIVISORE DI BAUD RATE IN MSB

INTENABLE EQU 03F9H ;REGISTRO DI ABILITAZIONE DELL'INTERRUZIONE

INTIDENTIF EQU 03FAH ;REGISTRO DI IDENTIFICAZIONE DELL'INTERRUZIONE

LINECTRL EQU 03FBH ;REGISTRO DI CONTROLLO DELLA LINEA

MODEMCTRL EQU 03FCH ;REGISTRO DI CONTROLLO DEL MODEM

LINESTATUS EQU 03FDH ;REGISTRO DI STATO DELLA LINEA

MODEMSTATUS EQU 03FEH ;REGISTRO DI STATO DEL MODEM








 BAUDRATEDIV DW 0060H ;DIVISOR: LOW=60, HIGH=00 ->BAUD =9600

 COUNTERCHAR  DB 0  ;CHARACTER COUNTER







 ;DW  256  DUP (?)





section .text


 global _start

 

 _start:

   

;PROGRAMMAZIONE 8250

   

   MOV DX,LINECTRL

   MOV AL,80H ;BIT 7=1 PER INDIRIZZARE IL BAUD RATE

   OUT DX,AL 

   

   MOV DX,BAUDLSB

   MOV AX,BAUDRATEDIV ;DEFINISCO FATTORE DI DIVISIONE

   OUT DX,AL

   MOV DX,BAUDMSB

   MOV AL,AH

   OUT DX,AL ;MSB

   

   MOV DX,LINECTRL 

   MOV AL,00000011B ;8 BIT DATO, 1 STOP, PARITA' NO

   OUT DX,AL

   

   MOV DX,MODEMCTRL

   MOV AL,00010011B ;BIT 4=0 PER NO LOOPBACK

   OUT DX,AL

   

   MOV DX,INTENABLE

   XOR AL,AL   ;DISABILITO TUTTI GLI INTERRUPTS

   OUT DX,AL

   

 CICLO:

   MOV DX,LINESTATUS 

   IN AL,DX  ;LEGGO IL REGISTRO DI STATO DELLA LINEA

   TEST AL,00011110B ;VERIFICO GLI ERRORI (4 TIPI)

   JNE ERRORI

   TEST AL,01H ;VERIFICO Rx PRONTO 

   JNE LEGGOCHAR

   TEST AL,20H ;VERIFICO Tx VUOTO

   JE CICLO

   

 ;SE SI ARRIVA A QUESTO PUNTO ALLORA L'8250 è PRONTO PER TRASMETTERE UN NUOVO CARATTERE

   MOV AH,1

   INT 80H

   JE CICLO

   

 ;SE SI ARRIVA A QUESTO PUNTO SIGNIFICA CHE ESISTE UN CARATTERE DA TASTIERA

   MOV AH,0

   INT 80H

 ;Al CONTIENE IL CARATTERE DELLA TASTIERA

   MOV DX,3F8H

   OUT DX,AL

   JMP CICLO

   

 LEGGOCHAR:

   MOV AL,[COUNTERCHAR]

   INC AL

   CMP AL,15

   JE FINE

   MOV [COUNTERCHAR],AL

   MOV DX,TXDATA

   IN AL,DX  ;AL CONTIENE IL CARATTERE RICEVUTO

   AND AL,7FH ;POICHè VI SONO 7 BIT DI DATO

   

 ;VISUALIZZAZIONE DEL CARATTERE 

   MOV BX,0

   MOV AH,14

   INT 80H

   POP AX

   CMP AL,0DH ;CONTROLLO SE RETURN

   JNE CICLO

     

 ;CAMBIO RIGA DI VISUALIZZAZIONE 

   MOV AL,0AH

   MOV BX,0

   MOV AH,14

   ;INT 10H
   INT 80H

   JMP CICLO

   

 ;GESTIONE ERRORI

 ERRORI:

   MOV DX,3F8H

   IN AL,DX

   MOV AL,'?'

   MOV BX,0

   MOV AH,14

   INT 80H

   JMP CICLO

   

 FINE:

   XOR AH,AH

   MOV AL,03

   INT 80H
```

When I compile this code "NASM -f bin UARTLOOP.asm", the compiler can create the UARTLOOP.o file without any errors. When I try to link the .o file with "ld UARTLOOP.o" it tells:

```
UARTLOOP.o: In function `_start':
UARTLOOP.asm:(.text+0xd): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_16 against `.data'
```

Have u got some ideas to solve this problem? Thx =)

**Update**

The output of `nasm -hf` is:

> usage: nasm [-@ response file] [-o outfile] [-f format] [-l listfile]
> [options...] [--] filename
> or nasm -v   for version info
>
> ```
> -t          assemble in SciTech TASM compatible mode
> -g          generate debug information in selected format.
> -E (or -e)  preprocess only (writes output to stdout by default)
> -a          don't preprocess (assemble only)
> -M          generate Makefile dependencies on stdout
> -MG         d:o, missing files assumed generated
>
> -Z<file>    redirect error messages to file
> -s          redirect error messages to stdout
>
> -F format   select a debugging format
>
> -I<path>    adds a pathname to the include file path
> -O<digit>   optimize branch offsets (-O0 disables, default)
> -P<file>    pre-includes a file
> -D<macro>[=<value>] pre-defines a macro
> -U<macro>   undefines a macro
> -X<format>  specifies error reporting format (gnu or vc)
> -w+foo      enables warning foo (equiv. -Wfoo)
> -w-foo      disable warning foo (equiv. -Wno-foo)
> ```

Comment: I don't exactly understand the error message, but you should try to use something like `-f elf`.
If if doesn't work, show us the output of `nasm -hf`.

Comment: Minimal example that generates the error and what it means: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32639540/895245

Answer (score 7):

This error comes from this:

```
               section .data
BAUDRATEDIV    DW 0060H

               section .text    
_start:
               MOV AX,BAUDRATEDIV
```

The problem is that BAUDRATEDIV is a memory location, not an assembly-time constant (EQU), so you should have written

```
            MOV AX,[BAUDRATEDIV]
```

The explanation for the error message is that you are trying to fit a 32/64 bits address into a 16 bits operand.

Comment: See also [Basic use of immediates vs. square brackets in YASM/NASM x86 assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10362511)

Answer (score -2):

```
Warnings:
error                   treat warnings as errors (default off)
macro-params            macro calls with wrong parameter count (default on)
macro-selfref           cyclic macro references (default off)
macro-defaults          macros with more default than optional parameters (default on)
orphan-labels           labels alone on lines without trailing `:' (default on)
number-overflow         numeric constant does not fit (default on)
gnu-elf-extensions      using 8- or 16-bit relocation in ELF32, a GNU extension (default off)
float-overflow          floating point overflow (default on)
float-denorm            floating point denormal (default off)
float-underflow         floating point underflow (default off)
float-toolong           too many digits in floating-point number (default on)
user                    %warning directives (default on)
```

Comment: That's `nasm`'s warning-option help.  Totally irrelevant and doesn't answer at all the question about *linker* errors when linking code that tries to put a symbol address into a 16-bit register.  That's legal to assemble (so NASM won't complain about it), but can't link into a normal executable.