# Basic use of immediates vs. square brackets in YASM/NASM x86 assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, memory-address, yasm

Suppose I have the following declared:

```
section .bss
buffer    resb     1
```

And these instructions follow in `section .text`:

```
mov    al, 5                    ; mov-immediate
mov    [buffer], al             ; store
mov    bl, [buffer]             ; load
mov    cl, buffer               ; mov-immediate?
```

Am I correct in understanding that bl will contain the value 5, and cl will contain the memory address of the variable `buffer`?

I am confused about the differences between

- moving an immediate into a register,
- moving a register into an immediate (what goes in, the data or the address?) and
- moving an immediate into a register without the brackets

  - For example, `mov cl, buffer` vs `mov cl, [buffer]`

---

UPDATE: After reading the responses, I suppose the following summary is accurate:

- `mov edi, array` puts the memory address of the zeroth array index in `edi`.  i.e. the label address.
- `mov byte [edi], 3` puts the VALUE 3 into the zeroth index of the array
- after `add edi, 3`, `edi` now contains the memory address of the 3rd index of the array
- `mov al, [array]` loads the DATA at the zeroth index into `al`.
- `mov al, [array+3]` loads the DATA at the third index into `al`.
- `mov [al], [array]` is invalid because [x86 can't encode 2 explicit memory operands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299077/assembly-moving-between-two-memory-addresses/53470709#53470709), and because `al` is only 8 bits and can't be used even in a 16-bit addressing mode.  [Referencing the contents of a memory location. (x86 addressing modes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34058101/referencing-the-contents-of-a-memory-location-x86-addressing-modes)
- `mov array, 3` is invalid, because you can't say "Hey, I don't like the offset at which `array` is stored, so I'll call it 3".  An immediate can only be a source operand.
- `mov byte [array], 3` puts the value 3 into the zeroth index (first byte) of the array.  [The `byte` specifier is needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44577130/when-should-i-use-size-directives-in-x86) to avoid ambiguity between byte/word/dword for instructions with  memory, immediate operands.  That would be an assemble-time error (ambiguous operand size) otherwise.

Please mention if any of these is false.  (editor's note: I fixed syntax errors / ambiguities so the valid ones actually *are* valid NASM syntax.  And linked other Q&As for details)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What do the brackets mean in x86 asm?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030366/what-do-the-brackets-mean-in-x86-asm)

Comment: `array resb 0` reserves a zero-length space at the label "array". If you want, say, a ten-entry array of byte entries in the .bss section, you should specify `resb 10`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Indeed, your thought is correct.That is, bl will contain 5 and cl the memory address of buffer(in fact the label buffer is a memory address itself).

---

Now, let me explain the differences between the operations you mentioned:

- moving an immediate into a register can be done using `mov reg,imm`.What may be confusing is that labels e.g buffer are immediate values themselves that contain an address.
- You cannot really move a register into an immediate, since immediate values are constants, like `2` or `FF1Ah`.What you can do is move a register to the place where the constant points to.You can do it like `mov [const], reg` .
- You can also use indirect addressing like `mov reg2,[reg1]` provided reg1 points to a valid location, and it will transfer the value pointed by reg1 to reg2.

---

So, `mov cl, buffer` will move the **address** of buffer to cl(which may or may not give the correct address, since cl is only one byte long) , whereas  `mov cl, [buffer]` will get the actual value.

### Summary

- When you use [a], then you refer to the value at the place where a points to.For example, if a is `F5B1`, then [a] refers to the address F5B1 in *RAM*.
- Labels are addresses,i.e values like `F5B1`.
- Values stored in registers do not have to be referenced to as [reg] because registers do not have addresses.In fact, registers can be thought of as immediate values.

Comment: I'm not well-versed at Assembly, but in the middle bullet point of your top section, shouldn't the last example line of assembly be the other way around? i.e., `mov [const], reg` ?

Comment: @Coldblackice: `mov [const], reg` is a store to memory, at the address `const`.  It's a weird choice of name, but all symbol addresses are link-time constants.  e.g. you could do `dd const` to emit a 4-byte absolute address somewhere (e.g. in a data section).  Or `const` can be a numeric address, e.g. if you're writing code that deals with legacy hardware like VGA memory at fixed memory addresses.  e.g `mov [0x0], ax` with the right value in DS.

Answer (score 26):

The square brackets essentially work like a dereference operator (e.g., like `*` in C).

So, something like

```
mov REG, x
```

moves the value of `x` into `REG`, whereas

```
mov REG, [x]
```

moves the value of the memory location where `x` points to into `REG`. Note that if `x` is a label, its value is the address of that label.

As for you're question:

> Am I correct in understanding that bl will contain the value 5, and cl
>   will contain the memory address of the variable buffer?

Yes, you are correct. But beware that, since `CL` is only 8 bits wide, it will only contain the least significant byte of the address of `buffer`.

Comment: `cl` will only contain the 8 least significant bits of the address.

Comment: @Alex: Yes, I just realized that:-)

Comment: when you say "if x is a label, its value is the address of that label" does that mean if x has the address of 0x1234 then the value when it's a label is 0x1234 as well?

Comment: @InstructionPointer: in MASM syntax, `mov eax, var` is a load, same as `[var]`.  In NASM syntax, `mov eax, var` is a mov-immediate of the label address.  (MASM syntax mov eax, OFFSET var`).  If you want a load, always use `mov eax, [var]` to avoid ambiguity.  If you want the address, there's no portable syntax that unambiguously means the address.  (Except in x86-64 PIC code where `lea rdi, [var]` is the best choice, assuming `default rel` for NASM syntax.  Except GAS .intel_syntax needs `lea rdi, [var + rip]` for the address with respect to the current location...)

Answer (score 6):

You are getting the idea. However, there are a few details worth bearing in mind:

1. Addresses can and usually are greater than what 8 bits can hold (`cl` is 8-bit, `cx` is 16-bit, `ecx` is 32-bit, `rcx` is 64-bit). So, `cl` is likely going to be unequal to the address of the variable `buffer`. It'll only have the least significant 8 bits of the address.
2. If there are interrupt routines or threads that can preempt the above code and/or access `buffer`, the value in `bl` may differ from 5. Broken interrupt routines may actually affect any register when they fail to preserve register values.

Comment: do not forget that ecx is only available in 386 or better and rcx in x86-64.

Comment: @byrondrossos: Correct. And x86 covers i80386.

Answer (score 4):

For all instruction with using immediate values as an operand for to write the value into a ram location (or for calculating within), we have to specify how many bytes we want to access. Because our assemble can not know if we want access only one **byte**, a **word**, or a **doppleword** for example if the immediate value is a lower value, like the following instructions shows.

```
array db 0FFh, 0FFh, 0FFh, 0FFh
mov byte [array], 3
```

results:

```
array db 03h, 0FFh, 0FFh, 0FFh
```

....

```
mov word [array], 3
```

results:

```
array db 03h, 00h, 0FFh, 0FFh
```

....

```
mov dword [array], 3
```

results:

```
array db 03h, 00h, 00h, 00h
```

Dirk