# Assembly: relocation truncated to fit r_x86_64_16 against '.data'

Tags: assembly, nasm

I have problems with my assembly code. This code for print text from file.

```
%define B_LENGTH 80
%define STDOUT 0x0001
SECTION .text
global _start
_start:
mov bp,STDOUT
mov ax, 0x3D00
mov dx,file_name
int 0x21
jc error
mov bx,ax
read_next:
mov ah,0x3F
mov dx,buffer
mov cx, B_LENGTH
int 0x21
jc error
xor ax,ax
jz end_reading
mov cx, ax
mov ah,0x40
xchg bp,bx
int 0x21
xchg bp,bx
jmp read_next
end_reading:
mov ah, 0x3E
int 0x21
mov al,0
endprog:
mov ah,4Ch
int 0x21
error:
mov al,1
jmp short endprog
SECTION .data
file_name db 'text.txt'
buffer times B_LENGTH db 0
```

For compile I use

```
nasm -felf64 task.asm -o task.o
ld -o task task.o
```

There what I see after compile

```
task.o: In function '_start':
task.asm: (.text+0xa): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_16 against '.data'
task.o: In function 'read_next':
task.asm: (.text+0x17): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_16 against '.data'
```

Can you help me to understand what the reason of this mistake?

Comment: That is 16 bit code for DOS. It's not gonna work as 64 bit elf on linux.

Comment: Ok, thanks, Jester.

Comment: `mov dx, buffer` warns that the address turned out not fit in 16 bits, so it had to truncate it during linker relocation.  The `_16` is the size, `x86_64` is the target.