# Setting bytes beyond 0x999 in the heap Segfaults assembly

Tags: assembly, segmentation-fault, x86-64, nasm, heap-memory

I'm trying to allocate `0x4000` bytes in the heap by uses the brk system call. However when doing this, trying to set anything after `0x999` segfaults. This is what I'm using:

```
global _start

section .data
    heapStart: dq 0 ; Start of the heap

section .text
_start:
    mov rax, 12 ; Heap call
    mov rdi, 0
    syscall ; Get the base pointer

    mov QWORD [heapStart], rax

    lea rdi, [rax + 0x4000]
    mov rax, 12
    syscall ; Allocate 8000 bytes

    mov rdi, heapStart

    mov BYTE [rdi + 0x1000], 'b' ; Errors "SIGSEGV"
    
    mov rax, 60 ; exit
    mov rdi, 0 ; error code
    syscall
```

Why does this happen? And how can I set bytes over `0x999`?

Comment: You want `mov rdi, [heapStart]` not `mov rdi, heapStart` which loads the address of the variable, not its value.

Comment: Just as a hex reminder, the next number after `0x999` isn't `0x1000` but `0x99a`.  The number preceding `0x1000` is `0xfff`.  And your `0x4000` allocates not 8000 bytes but 16384.

Comment: Memory protection works in chunks of 4k pages.  Writing past the end of space you reserved in `.data` won't fault until you cross into an unmapped page.  [Is it safe to read past the end of a buffer within the same page on x86 and x64?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37800739).  Err, I guess you didn't intend to offset relative to the address of `heapStart`, but rather to the return value of the 2nd brk syscall.  [Basic use of immediates vs. square brackets in YASM/NASM x86 assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10362511) covers that, the first dup is why it didn't crash with smaller offsets.