# why dec [count] is used instead of dec count in x86 assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I am unable to understand why `dec [count]` is used ( assuming of course, count is declared in .data section ) something similar to

```
section .data
        count dw 0
        value db 15

section .text
        global _start

_start:
        dec [count]
```

is used instead of using `dec count`, won't  `dec [count]` decrement the the content at address `count`?

Comment: See also: [Basic use of immediates vs. square brackets in YASM/NASM x86 assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10362511/555045) (for MASM it works in a different way but this isn't MASM-compatible code)

Comment: @harold I am using nasm, would that make a substantial difference?

Comment: *"won't `dec [count]` decrement the the content at address count"* - yeah, that's exactly what it does. Where's the problem exactly? It's just decrementing a variable stored in memory in the `.data` section, whose address is `count`.

Comment: Yes NASM vs MASM makes a substantial difference, square bracket usage in NASM is very regular, but [not so regular in MASM](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25129743/555045).

Comment: Thank you, I think I am starting to understand now. Appreciate the help.