# NASM relocation truncated to fit: R_386_16 against `.data'

Tags: linux, assembly, linker, nasm

So I'm noob on NASM and Linux and I'm doing this program so I can count character on an string given on the Command Line, Before I was trying to create my own procedures to Write and Read on the Terminal, but then my professor told me to start using the macros on the **io.mac** file that comes with a book from Sirvarama. But when I started using it I got this linking error that I don't know what it Means or how to fix It, so if you could help me, I will appreciate it.

Thanks, sorry for my average sloopy English as you could see in the code and the comments, Spanish is mi first language =D

PD:
This is how I'm assembling and linking:

```
bernal@ubuntu:~/Arqui$ nasm -f elf32 ContChar.asm -l ContChar.lst
bernal@ubuntu:~/Arqui$ ld -m elf_i386 -o ContChar ContChar.o io.o
ContChar.o: In function `ciclo':
ContChar.asm:(.text+0x72): relocation truncated to fit: R_386_16 against `.data'
```

```
%include  "io.mac"

.DATA

    ;Equivalencias
     sys_exit:      equ 1
     sys_read:      equ 3
     sys_write:     equ 4
     stdin:         equ 0
     stdout:        equ 1
     stderr:        equ 3


    ;Strings
    ASCII:              db  'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',0 ; Letras ASCII
    lenASCII:       equ $ - ASCII   
    myString:           db  'AabBb;Aa_ AhDC',0 ; String a Evaluar
    lenMyString:    equ $ - myString
    yes:                db  'YES',0 ; String Random para debuguear
    lenYes:         equ $ - yes 

    ;Mensajes
    msg1                db "Ingrese algo: ",10,0
    lenMsg1:        equ $ - msg1
    msg2:               db  "Elija Modo:",10,0
    lenMsg2:        equ $ - msg2
    msgCantS:           db "Cantidad de Espacios: "
    lenMsgCantS:    equ $ - msgCantS
    msgCantO:           db "Cantidad de Otros Caracteres: "
    lenMsgCantO:    equ $ - msgCantO

    ;Contadores
    contASCII: times 52     db   0 ; Contador de Letras ASCII
    contSpace:              db   0  ; Contador de Espacios
    contOther:              db   0  ; Contador de Simbolos Extraños

    leninput                db   0

.UDATA
    input:      resb    80
    ;leninput   resb    1
    modo:       resb    1

.CODE

    .STARTUP
    xor ebx, ebx

    PutStr msg1

    mov ecx, input
    mov edx, 300
    call LeerProc
    sub eax,1

    add [leninput],eax

    nwln

    PutStr msg2

    mov ecx,modo
    mov edx,1
    call LeerProc
    pop eax

    mov ebx,input               ;Asigna myString a EBX
    mov ecx,eax                 ;Asigna el largo de myString a ECX 
    ciclo:

        mov AL,[EBX]            ; Pasa el char a AL
        call Proc_Comparar      ; Cuenta el char en el contASCII
        ;call proc_PrintEnter   ;
        inc EBX                 ; Incrementa el EBX para seguir con el siguiente char

    loop ciclo

    nwln

    PutStr ASCII

    nwln

    PutInt contASCII

    nwln

    PutStr msgCantS

    PutStr contSpace

    nwln

    PutStr msgCantO

    PutStr contOther

    nwln

    call Proc_PrintContadores

    jmp Terminar


Proc_Comparar:
    push EBX                    
    push AX                     
    push ecx                    

    ; mov ecx,ebx               ; Pasa el char a ECX
    ; mov edx,1                 ; Asigna el largo de char(1) a EDX
    ; call EscribirProc             ; Muestra el caracter en Pantalla

    cmp AL,'a'                  ; revisa si el char es menor que la letra 'a' minuscula 
    jl  not_lowercase           ; si lo es lo envía a not_lowercase si lo es continua
    cmp AL,'z'                  ; revisa si el char es una letra minuscula al comparar si es mayor que la letra 'z'
    jg  not_letter              ; si es mayor asume que no es una letra y lo envía a not_letter
    jmp lowercase               ; al haber pasado por todo se da cuenta que se trata de una letra minuscula

    lowercase:
        mov EBX,26              ; Se mueve 26 a EBX para que comience en ASCII a partir de las letras minusculas
        cicloL:
            cmp AL,[ASCII+EBX]  ; Compara el char en evaluacion con cada letra ascii minuscula
            jz Found            ; Cuando encuentra el caracter al que es igual salta a Found
            inc EBX             ; Si no lo encuentra aumenta el EBX para seguir comparando con el siguiente caracter
            jmp cicloL          ; Repite el cicloL


    not_lowercase:
        cmp AL,'Z'              ; Revisa si el char es mayor a  la letra 'Z' 
        jg not_letter           ; Si lo es entonces asume que no es una letra pues ya se sabe que no es una letra minuscula y ahora tampoco mayuscula
        cmp AL,'A'              ; Revisa si el char es menor a la letra 'A'
        jl not_letter           ; Si lo es entonces asume que no es una letra pues ya se sabe que no es una letra minuscula y ahora tampoco mayuscula

        mov EBX, 0              ; Asigna un 0 a EBX 
        cicloU:                 ;CicloU hace lo mismo que CicloL solo que con letras mayusculas
            cmp AL,[ASCII+EBX]  
            jz Found
            inc EBX
            jmp cicloU


    not_letter:                 ; Llega aquí cuando no es una letra
        cmp AL,' '              ; Revisa si el char es un Espacio
        jz  Space               ; Si lo es salta a Space
        jmp OtherChar           ; Si no lo es salta a OtherChar

    Space:
        inc byte [contSpace]    ; Incrementa el contador de espacios
        jmp Fin_Comparar        ; Sale del Proceso
    OtherChar:
        inc byte [contOther]    ; Incrementa el contador de otros chars
        jmp Fin_Comparar        ; Sale del Proceso

    Found:
        inc byte [contASCII+EBX] ; Incrementa el contador de la letra que encontró

    Fin_Comparar:               ; Sale del Proceso
        pop  ecx
        pop  AX
        pop  ebx
        ret

Proc_PrintContadores:
    push ecx
    push eax
    push ebx
    push edx

    mov EBX,ASCII               ; Se da la dirección de los caracteres ascii para ver que letra se evalua
    mov ECX,0                   ; Se inicializa en 0 para utilizarlo como indice
    cicloCont:

        mov AL,[contASCII+ECX]  ; Pasa el número del contadorASCII al AL
        cmp AL,0                ; Cmp AL con 0 para saber si se contó la la letra respectiva 
        jg  printASCII          ; Si encuentra algo mayor a 0 procede a imprimirlo
        inc EBX                 ; Incrementa el EBX para continuar con la siguiente letra
        inc ECX                 ; Incrementa el ECX para aumentar el "indice" en los contadores
        cmp ECX,53              ; Se revisa si ya comparo todas las letras ascii ya que en total son 52
        jz  EndPrintCont        ; Si así es termina el Proceso
        jmp cicloCont           ; Repite el cicloCont

    printASCII:
        push ECX

        PutCh [ASCII+ECX]

        PutCh ':'

        Pop ECX
        PutInt [contASCII+ECX]
        Push ECX
        pop ECX

        inc EBX                 ; Incrementa el EBX para continuar con la siguiente letra
        inc ECX                 ; Incrementa el ECX para aumentar el "indice" en los contadores
        cmp ECX,53  
        jmp cicloCont

    EndPrintCont:
        pop  edx
        pop  ebx
        pop  eax
        pop  ecx

        ret

 Proc_printASCII:
         push ecx
         push EBX


         TwoPoints:                 ; Pasa al ecx : para imprimirlos
            mov  ecx,':'
            mov  edx,1
            call EscribirProc
            jmp ImprimirCantidad

         ImprimirCantidad:          ; imprime la cantidad que se almacena en contASCII de la letra respectiva
            mov  ecx,[contASCII+EBX]
            mov  edx,1
            call EscribirProc

         pop  EBX
         pop  ecx

         ret


LeerProc:
    push ebx

    mov eax, sys_read
    mov ebx, stdin
    int 80h

    pop ebx

    ret

proc_PrintYes:
        push edx
        push ecx
        push eax
        push ebx

        mov edx,lenYes  
        mov ecx,yes 
        mov ebx,1   
        mov eax,4   
        int 80h 
        ;call proc_PrintEnter

        pop ebx
        pop eax
        pop ecx
        pop edx 


Terminar:
    .EXIT
```

The io.mac:

```
    extern   proc_nwln, proc_PutCh, proc_PutStr
    extern   proc_GetStr, proc_GetCh
    extern   proc_PutInt, proc_GetInt
    extern   proc_PutLInt, proc_GetLInt

    ;;-------------------------------------------------------------------
    %macro  .STARTUP  0
    ;group dgroup .data .bss
            global   _start
    _start:
    %endmacro
    ;;-------------------------------------------------------------------


    ;;-------------------------------------------------------------------
    %macro  .EXIT  0
            mov    EAX,1
            xor    EBX,EBX
            int    0x80
    %endmacro
    ;;-------------------------------------------------------------------


    ;;-------------------------------------------------------------------
    %macro  .DATA 0
            segment .data
    %endmacro
    ;;-------------------------------------------------------------------

    ;;-------------------------------------------------------------------
    %macro  .UDATA 0
            segment .bss
    %endmacro
    ;;-------------------------------------------------------------------

    ;;-------------------------------------------------------------------
    %macro  .CODE 0
            segment .data
            segment .bss
            segment .text
    %endmacro
    ;;-------------------------------------------------------------------


    ;;-------------------------------------------------------------------
    %macro  nwln  0 
            call    proc_nwln
    %endmacro
    ;;-------------------------------------------------------------------


    ;;-------------------------------------------------------------------
    %macro  PutCh  1 
            push    AX
            mov     AL,%1
            call    proc_PutCh
            pop     AX
    %endmacro
    ;;-------------------------------------------------------------------


    ;;-------------------------------------------------------------------
    %macro  PutStr  1 
            push    ECX
            mov     ECX,%1
            call    proc_PutStr
            pop     ECX
    %endmacro
    ;;-------------------------------------------------------------------


    ;;-------------------------------------------------------------------
    %macro  GetStr  1-2 81
            push    ESI
            push    EDI
            mov     EDI,%1
            mov     ESI,%2
            call    proc_GetStr
            pop     EDI
            pop     ESI
    %endmacro
    ;;-------------------------------------------------------------------


    ;;-------------------------------------------------------------------
    %macro  GetCh   1
            push    SI
            xor     SI,SI
    %ifidni %1,AL
            ;inc     SI
            call    proc_GetCh
    %elifidni %1,AH
            mov     SI,1
            call    proc_GetCh
    %else
            push    AX
            call    proc_GetCh
            mov     %1,AL
            pop     AX
    %endif
            pop     SI
    %endmacro
    ;;-------------------------------------------------------------------


    ;;-------------------------------------------------------------------
    %macro  PutInt  1
            push    AX
            mov     AX,%1
            call    proc_PutInt
            pop     AX
    %endmacro
    ;;-------------------------------------------------------------------


    ;;-------------------------------------------------------------------
    %macro  GetInt  1
    %ifnidni %1,AX
            push    AX
            call    proc_GetInt
            mov     %1,AX
          pop     AX
    %else 
            call  proc_GetInt
    %endif
    %endmacro
    ;;-------------------------------------------------------------------

    ;;-------------------------------------------------------------------
    %macro  PutLInt  1
            push    EAX
            mov     EAX,%1
            call    proc_PutLInt
            pop     EAX
    %endmacro
    ;;-------------------------------------------------------------------

    ;;-------------------------------------------------------------------
    %macro  GetLInt  1
    %ifnidni %1,EAX
            push    EAX
            call    proc_GetLInt
            mov     %1,EAX
          pop     EAX
    %else 
            call  proc_GetLInt
    %endif
    %endmacro
    ;;-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So here is the result of the objdump -dr ContChar.o:

bernal@ubuntu:~/Arqui$ objdump -dr ContChar.o

```
  ContChar.o:     file format elf32-i386


  Disassembly of section .text:

  00000000 <_start>:
     0: 31 db                   xor    %ebx,%ebx
     2: 51                      push   %ecx
     3: b9 48 00 00 00          mov    $0x48,%ecx
            4: R_386_32 .data
     8: e8 fc ff ff ff          call   9 <_start+0x9>
            9: R_386_PC32   proc_PutStr
     d: 59                      pop    %ecx
     e: b9 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%ecx
            f: R_386_32 .bss
    13: ba 2c 01 00 00          mov    $0x12c,%edx
    18: e8 7f 01 00 00          call   19c <LeerProc>
    1d: 83 e8 01                sub    $0x1,%eax
    20: 01 05 cf 00 00 00       add    %eax,0xcf
            22: R_386_32    .data
    26: e8 fc ff ff ff          call   27 <_start+0x27>
            27: R_386_PC32  proc_nwln
    2b: 51                      push   %ecx
    2c: b9 58 00 00 00          mov    $0x58,%ecx
            2d: R_386_32    .data
    31: e8 fc ff ff ff          call   32 <_start+0x32>
            32: R_386_PC32  proc_PutStr
    36: 59                      pop    %ecx
    37: b9 50 00 00 00          mov    $0x50,%ecx
            38: R_386_32    .bss
    3c: ba 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%edx
    41: e8 56 01 00 00          call   19c <LeerProc>
    46: 58                      pop    %eax
    47: bb 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%ebx
            48: R_386_32    .bss
    4c: 89 c1                   mov    %eax,%ecx

  0000004e <ciclo>:
    4e: 8a 03                   mov    (%ebx),%al
    50: e8 6f 00 00 00          call   c4 <Proc_Comparar>
    55: 43                      inc    %ebx
    56: e2 f6                   loop   4e <ciclo>
    58: e8 fc ff ff ff          call   59 <ciclo+0xb>
            59: R_386_PC32  proc_nwln
    5d: 51                      push   %ecx
    5e: b9 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%ecx
            5f: R_386_32    .data
    63: e8 fc ff ff ff          call   64 <ciclo+0x16>
            64: R_386_PC32  proc_PutStr
    68: 59                      pop    %ecx
    69: e8 fc ff ff ff          call   6a <ciclo+0x1c>
            6a: R_386_PC32  proc_nwln
    6e: 66 50                   push   %ax
    70: 66 b8 99 00             mov    $0x99,%ax
            72: R_386_16    .data
    74: e8 fc ff ff ff          call   75 <ciclo+0x27>
            75: R_386_PC32  proc_PutInt
    79: 66 58                   pop    %ax
    7b: e8 fc ff ff ff          call   7c <ciclo+0x2e>
            7c: R_386_PC32  proc_nwln
    80: 51                      push   %ecx
    81: b9 65 00 00 00          mov    $0x65,%ecx
            82: R_386_32    .data
    86: e8 fc ff ff ff          call   87 <ciclo+0x39>
            87: R_386_PC32  proc_PutStr
    8b: 59                      pop    %ecx
    8c: 51                      push   %ecx
    8d: b9 cd 00 00 00          mov    $0xcd,%ecx
            8e: R_386_32    .data
    92: e8 fc ff ff ff          call   93 <ciclo+0x45>
            93: R_386_PC32  proc_PutStr
    97: 59                      pop    %ecx
    98: e8 fc ff ff ff          call   99 <ciclo+0x4b>
            99: R_386_PC32  proc_nwln
    9d: 51                      push   %ecx
    9e: b9 7b 00 00 00          mov    $0x7b,%ecx
            9f: R_386_32    .data
    a3: e8 fc ff ff ff          call   a4 <ciclo+0x56>
            a4: R_386_PC32  proc_PutStr
    a8: 59                      pop    %ecx
    a9: 51                      push   %ecx
    aa: b9 ce 00 00 00          mov    $0xce,%ecx
            ab: R_386_32    .data
    af: e8 fc ff ff ff          call   b0 <ciclo+0x62>
            b0: R_386_PC32  proc_PutStr
    b4: 59                      pop    %ecx
    b5: e8 fc ff ff ff          call   b6 <ciclo+0x68>
            b6: R_386_PC32  proc_nwln
    ba: e8 5c 00 00 00          call   11b <Proc_PrintContadores>
    bf: e9 16 01 00 00          jmp    1da <Terminar>

  000000c4 <Proc_Comparar>:
    c4: 53                      push   %ebx
    c5: 66 50                   push   %ax
    c7: 51                      push   %ecx
    c8: 3c 61                   cmp    $0x61,%al
    ca: 7c 16                   jl     e2 <not_lowercase>
    cc: 3c 7a                   cmp    $0x7a,%al
    ce: 7f 2a                   jg     fa <not_letter>
    d0: eb 00                   jmp    d2 <lowercase>

  000000d2 <lowercase>:
    d2: bb 1a 00 00 00          mov    $0x1a,%ebx

  000000d7 <cicloL>:
    d7: 3a 83 00 00 00 00       cmp    0x0(%ebx),%al
            d9: R_386_32    .data
    dd: 74 31                   je     110 <Found>
    df: 43                      inc    %ebx
    e0: eb f5                   jmp    d7 <cicloL>

  000000e2 <not_lowercase>:
    e2: 3c 5a                   cmp    $0x5a,%al
    e4: 7f 14                   jg     fa <not_letter>
    e6: 3c 41                   cmp    $0x41,%al
    e8: 7c 10                   jl     fa <not_letter>
    ea: bb 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%ebx

  000000ef <cicloU>:
    ef: 3a 83 00 00 00 00       cmp    0x0(%ebx),%al
            f1: R_386_32    .data
    f5: 74 19                   je     110 <Found>
    f7: 43                      inc    %ebx
    f8: eb f5                   jmp    ef <cicloU>

  000000fa <not_letter>:
    fa: 3c 20                   cmp    $0x20,%al
    fc: 74 02                   je     100 <Space>
    fe: eb 08                   jmp    108 <OtherChar>

  00000100 <Space>:
   100: fe 05 cd 00 00 00       incb   0xcd
            102: R_386_32   .data
   106: eb 0e                   jmp    116 <Fin_Comparar>

  00000108 <OtherChar>:
   108: fe 05 ce 00 00 00       incb   0xce
            10a: R_386_32   .data
   10e: eb 06                   jmp    116 <Fin_Comparar>

  00000110 <Found>:
   110: fe 83 99 00 00 00       incb   0x99(%ebx)
            112: R_386_32   .data

  00000116 <Fin_Comparar>:
   116: 59                      pop    %ecx
   117: 66 58                   pop    %ax
   119: 5b                      pop    %ebx
   11a: c3                      ret    

  0000011b <Proc_PrintContadores>:
   11b: 51                      push   %ecx
   11c: 50                      push   %eax
   11d: 53                      push   %ebx
   11e: 52                      push   %edx
   11f: bb 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%ebx
            120: R_386_32   .data
   124: b9 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%ecx

  00000129 <cicloCont>:
   129: 8a 81 99 00 00 00       mov    0x99(%ecx),%al
            12b: R_386_32   .data
   12f: 3c 00                   cmp    $0x0,%al
   131: 7f 09                   jg     13c <printASCII>
   133: 43                      inc    %ebx
   134: 41                      inc    %ecx
   135: 83 f9 35                cmp    $0x35,%ecx
   138: 74 37                   je     171 <EndPrintCont>
   13a: eb ed                   jmp    129 <cicloCont>

  0000013c <printASCII>:
   13c: 51                      push   %ecx
   13d: 66 50                   push   %ax
   13f: 8a 81 00 00 00 00       mov    0x0(%ecx),%al
            141: R_386_32   .data
   145: e8 fc ff ff ff          call   146 <printASCII+0xa>
            146: R_386_PC32 proc_PutCh
   14a: 66 58                   pop    %ax
   14c: 66 50                   push   %ax
   14e: b0 3a                   mov    $0x3a,%al
   150: e8 fc ff ff ff          call   151 <printASCII+0x15>
            151: R_386_PC32 proc_PutCh
   155: 66 58                   pop    %ax
   157: 59                      pop    %ecx
   158: 66 50                   push   %ax
   15a: 66 8b 81 99 00 00 00    mov    0x99(%ecx),%ax
            15d: R_386_32   .data
   161: e8 fc ff ff ff          call   162 <printASCII+0x26>
            162: R_386_PC32 proc_PutInt
   166: 66 58                   pop    %ax
   168: 51                      push   %ecx
   169: 59                      pop    %ecx
   16a: 43                      inc    %ebx
   16b: 41                      inc    %ecx
   16c: 83 f9 35                cmp    $0x35,%ecx
   16f: eb b8                   jmp    129 <cicloCont>

  00000171 <EndPrintCont>:
   171: 5a                      pop    %edx
   172: 5b                      pop    %ebx
   173: 58                      pop    %eax
   174: 59                      pop    %ecx
   175: c3                      ret    

  00000176 <Proc_printASCII>:
   176: 51                      push   %ecx
   177: 53                      push   %ebx

  00000178 <TwoPoints>:
   178: b9 3a 00 00 00          mov    $0x3a,%ecx
   17d: ba 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%edx
   182: e8 42 00 00 00          call   1c9 <EscribirProc>
   187: eb 00                   jmp    189 <ImprimirCantidad>

  00000189 <ImprimirCantidad>:
   189: 8b 8b 99 00 00 00       mov    0x99(%ebx),%ecx
            18b: R_386_32   .data
   18f: ba 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%edx
   194: e8 30 00 00 00          call   1c9 <EscribirProc>
   199: 5b                      pop    %ebx
   19a: 59                      pop    %ecx
   19b: c3                      ret    

  0000019c <LeerProc>:
   19c: 53                      push   %ebx
   19d: b8 03 00 00 00          mov    $0x3,%eax
   1a2: bb 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%ebx
   1a7: cd 80                   int    $0x80
   1a9: 5b                      pop    %ebx
   1aa: c3                      ret    

  000001ab <proc_PrintYes>:
   1ab: 52                      push   %edx
   1ac: 51                      push   %ecx
   1ad: 50                      push   %eax
   1ae: 53                      push   %ebx
   1af: ba 04 00 00 00          mov    $0x4,%edx
   1b4: b9 44 00 00 00          mov    $0x44,%ecx
            1b5: R_386_32   .data
   1b9: bb 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%ebx
   1be: b8 04 00 00 00          mov    $0x4,%eax
   1c3: cd 80                   int    $0x80
   1c5: 5b                      pop    %ebx
   1c6: 58                      pop    %eax
   1c7: 59                      pop    %ecx
   1c8: 5a                      pop    %edx

  000001c9 <EscribirProc>:
   1c9: 50                      push   %eax
   1ca: 53                      push   %ebx
   1cb: b8 04 00 00 00          mov    $0x4,%eax
   1d0: bb 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%ebx
   1d5: cd 80                   int    $0x80
   1d7: 5b                      pop    %ebx
   1d8: 58                      pop    %eax
   1d9: c3                      ret    

  000001da <Terminar>:
   1da: b8 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%eax
   1df: 31 db                   xor    %ebx,%ebx
   1e1: cd 80                   int    $0x80
```

Comment: We will also need `io.mac`. Presumably it is loading an address into a 16 bit register. Alternatively, do `objdump -dr ContChar.o` and see where you have a `R_386_16` relocation.

Comment: Try `PutInt [contASCII]` instead of `PutInt contASCII`. You are trying to print the address not the value. Still, that `io.mac` is quite a mess of 16 and 32 bit code.

Comment: Also [Relocation Truncated to Fit error in NASM x86\_64](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2720161) for the specific linker error message.